# What is my overseas Hardware and how to Flash it?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, hardware, android-10, google-search

My phone was bought online and it came from overseas. Various **benchmarks** have determined that my phone's Android system and hardware ***does not*** match the description given on the site or the About Phone section. The **About Phone** section says my system is an ***Android 10*** and that I'm running an **eight core processor** with 12 gigs of RAM and 512 gigs of an internal storage.

The various benchmarks determines that I'm running **Android 8.1**. That I have less than 1 gig of RAM and only 8 gigs of internal storage and a ***4 core processor***.

I cannot get a clear-cut picture of my entire system to be able to **Flash** it properly. Is there an app or a website system that isn't going to charge me, that can determine any of the specifics that I need so that I can Flash a new ROM or Find and Flash for me?

I have done every possible search that I know of considering that I am not all that fluent with this area. Most of the benchmarks say that I'm running an ***Alps manufactured machine.*** But I can't verify that they are the manufacturer or that they even have manufactured a phone. So I really need some help. Any help that can be given, I would be greatly appreciative

Comment: Looks like you got a forged phone. Reclaim your money and send the commerce platform the info that the seller is a fraud.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to find out what the hardware is so that I can find the proper ROM in flash it. I don't know that just seems a little anticlimactic considering I know what software can do.

Comment: Well it was your decision to buy an non-name phone from an dubious oversea vendor. Even if the hardware would have been as specified the software of such products is always a problem.

Comment: And not one of that can argue with. But I still think that I can find some apps somewhere that will give me the information that I need about the current hardware that is machine takes up and be able to compile a ROM or find a ROM that will work. So really I don't know if I'm missing anything or not because I'm sure if I find the right parts and a can assemble it then it should work right?